# The residual field of $\operatorname{Spec}(\prod_{p} \overline{\mathbb{F}_p})$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, filters

Let $I$ be a set and $\mathfrak{U}$ be the set of all ultrafilters on $I$. If $E \subset I$ we define $\mathfrak{U}_E$ to be the set consisting of those elements of $\mathfrak{U}$ which contain $E$. We can endow $\mathfrak{U}$ with a topology for which a basis of open sets is given by the $\mathfrak{U}_E$'s.

Let $(k_i)_{i\in I}$ be family of fields and put $A = \prod_{i \in I} k_i$. We can then show that for each $\mathscr{F} \in \mathfrak{U}$ $ \mathfrak{m}_{\mathscr{F}} = \{ (x_i)_{i\in I} \in A \;|\; \{i \in I \;|\; x_i = 0 \} \in \mathscr{F} \}$ is a maximal ideal of $A$.

Furthermore the map $\mathscr{F} \mapsto \mathfrak{m}_{\mathscr{F}}$ is a homeomorphism from $\mathfrak{U}$ to \operatorname{Spec}(A)$.

I've more or less been able to show all of this. But now I'm asked (this is from an old exam from my algebraic geometry course) to show that if $I$ is the set of prime numbers, $k_i = \overline{\mathbb{F}_i}$ and $\xi \in \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is a point corresponding to a non principal ultrafiler of $I$ then $\kappa(\xi)$ (the residual field of $\xi$) is an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.

I haven't been able to prove this so I'm wondering if anyone can suggest a solution. I'm in fact even more interested in a reference for this result because I find it really cool (and I could check wether what I've done is correct).

For information this is exercise $4$ of this exam (in french), you will find more details about ultrafilters in there : http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~lepage/TD/GeoAlg/termgeo-alg2012.pdf

Comment: Man, algebraic geometry makes model theory so hard to understand. *Goes to prepare the cross for the upcoming crucifixion...*

Comment: Well, if I have to say, I don't see how this question has much to do with set theory. Elementary or not. Model theory, sure, but that's 'bout that.

Comment: Well the description of the tag elementary-set theory seemed to fit the ultra-filters part. I'd be happy to take it away. On the other I would rather not put model-theory as a tag since I know nothing about it.

Answer (score 3):

That is in fact a very simple exercise in model theory.

First one has to write down the first-order theory of fields, and add the schema specifying that a field is algebraically closed. That is, $\forall x_0\ldots\forall x_n\exists y(x_ny^n+\ldots+x_1y+x_0=0)$.

Now Łoś theorem tells us that the ultraproduct is a field, and that it is in fact algebraically closed. This is because the ultraproduct satisfies a sentence if and only if the set of indices of structures satisfying this sentence is large (in the ultrafilter). And all of them satisfy these part of the theory.

To see that the characteristics is $0$, note that for every $p$ the set of fields whose characteristic is larger than $p$ is large (in fact cofinite). Therefore the product satisfies $1+1\neq 0$ and $1+1+1\neq 0$ and so on. Which is the same thing as saying that it has characteristic $0$.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot ! I have to say though ... I know nothing of model theory. I am guesing the teacher had an other solution in mind since the students really weren't supposed to know any model theory.

Comment: I suppose it amounts to verifying all the above by hand. Which sounds like awfully lot of hard work. And for zero good reasons, too!

Comment: :-) Anyway trying to learn at least a little bit of model theory is high on my to-do list so this will give me extra-motivation so that I can understand you answer. Thanks again.

Comment: If you do have an arsenal of theorems promising it is algebraically closed, verifying that it has characteristic zero shouldn't be *that* hard, though.